# how to move product title above image on category page in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I would like to move the product title above the product image on the shop category page.

Which hook can do that in `functions.php`?

I tried this one:

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
```

---

but didn't work